# Azure Logic App HTTP request 500

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am new to the Azure Logic Apps so this example may look not that useful but its just to learn some basic Azure Logic.

I got a simple HTTP listener (When an HTTP request is received)
Than it should send another HTTP GET request to some service and send a response to the first caller.
It looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVQOR.jpg

Now everything is working great until i send wrong data or somehow the Logic apps get a 500 HTTP error from the HTTP requests.

Than the Logic app hangs in the HTTP request for around 1 minute and fails.
The Response after that is never send.

How can i forward the response that the Logic app is getting back to the requester who requested the logic app?

Answer (score 2):

Logic Apps would retry any failing request 4 times by default, hence you see increased runtime when the http service returns error 5xx. You can configure this behaviour using a custom retry policy. See more https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/customizable-retry-policies-in-logic-apps/

By default, Logic App steps have a dependency on the success of any dependent actions. This results in your response action being skipped when the http action fails.

You have a couple of options to solve this:

1. In code view, you can update the `runAfter` property so that the action runs regardless of whether the http action succeeded or not

   ```
   "runAfter": { "Condition": [ "Succeeded", "Failed" ] }
   ```
2. Add a condition to your Logic Apps on the http status code of the http action, and then have a dedicated `Response` action for each case

Comment: You mean [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt643939.aspx) right.

I am getting the following error when trying to add a retryPolicy:
Could not find member 'retryPolicy' on object of type 'FlowTemplateAction'. Path 'properties.definition.actions.HTTP.retryPolicy',

This is my code (the Condition is already to Succeeded and Failed):
http://pastebin.com/igfprKFT

Also for 4xx errors it works fine and only for 5xx it takes 1min to timeout.
http://imgur.com/a/0nBPK
After the timeout the response is not fired

Comment: Looks like you are specifying the retryPolicy directly under action. It needs to be under the inputs property. Regarding failures, Logic Apps only retry intermittent failures (so 5xx status codes), 4xx status codes are treated as deterministic failures, and so are not retried

Comment: Can I overwrite 4 times rerun attempts behaviour? Is there place to do it in Logic App designer or do I have to edit json?

Comment: Thanks for the runAfter tip, it was exactly what I needed for my use case :)

Answer (score 1):

You can update retry policy and timeout setting of Http action as

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KW7X.png)

Comment: Please add a description of the image you have linked.

Answer (score 0):

As you know 500 is something an unknown error and hence logicapp engine stops processing any actions which keep throwing 500 even after the retry. For this specific case you need to setup logicapp diagnostics rule "Actions Failed"/"Runs Failed". In the rule you can configure sending an email and/ configure a webhook to react to the event

Comment: When i add another Response nothing changes, also my code is working for 4xx errors but not for 5xx...

Comment: As you know 500 is something an unknown error and hence logicapp engine stops processing any actions which keep throwing 500 even after the retry. For this specific case you need to setup logicapp diagnostics rule "Actions Failed"/"Runs Failed". In the rule you can configure sending an email and/ configure a webhook to react to the event.